# Class Random only Generates 0

Tags: java, class, random

Okay

I have The problem that i want to generate 64 numbers between 0 and 1 (that means 0 or 1)

the function i have currently is:

```
public static int randNr(int max) {
Random r = new Random();
int o = r.nextInt(max);
return o;
}
```

But it always returns 0.
Is there any way to make that it generates also a 1 ?

EDIT:

the function is located in a different java file than when i calling it!

Comment: What is the value of max?. You get random numbers upto "max"

Comment: Did you notice that the max is **exclusive** ? To generate 0 or 1, you need to pass 2.

Comment: @user2864740: you're right, I was confusing with .NET where it will generate the same values (in Java it doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1) `nextInt(max);` generates a number from 0 and up to but **not including** `max`. My guess is that you're passing 1 as `max`. Pass 2 and all will be well.

2) Creating a new generator object each time ruins the statistical properties of the generator. You should create one `Random` instance and (i) either pass into the function or (ii) have the instance stored as a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

This function works fine. You are probably calling it with the *wrong arguments*. It should be:

```
randNr(2)
```

**Why?** Because it's using the `Random#nextInt(max)` method, which will return a random integer in the range `[0, max-1]` (including `0` and `max-1`).

**Note:** It's not recommended to create a new `Random` object each time you call the function. One solution would be to declare the `Random` object as an `static` member of the class:

```
public class Test
{
    private static Random r = new Random();
    // ...
}
```

Another solution would be to use the `static` method `Math.random()`<sup>1</sup>:

```
int o = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
```

---

<sup>1: Could someone confirm if this method is faster than the OP's one?</sup>

Comment: Nice answer as you address the main point, but the misuse of the `Random` object is not just about efficiency but, more importantly, it's about the fact that the distribution of the random numbers will not have the correct statistical properties.

Comment: @Bathsheba can you explain it a little better? I tested it and it appears to give correct results.

Comment: No your solution is correct. I just don't like the emphasis on efficiency. There are many scientific papers out there that are bunk due to random number misuse. A random number sequence drawing 0 and 1 should have a mean of 1/2 and a variance of 1/4. I doubt that the sequence produced when continuously setting the random generator seed to the system clock has even those properties.

Comment: You *may* be right. But I still thinking that it's inefficient and not practical to create a *1-use-object* on each iteration.

Comment: @Bathsheba You're both right. Modern CPUs are so fast that it is possible to instantiate many PRNG instances with identical seeding, which destroys the correlation and distributional behaviors across instances. From an efficiency point of view, it's like digging a new well every time you want a glass of water rather than digging a single well and going back to it for as many glasses of water as you need.